# Add custom fields in Magento 2 plugin

Tags: magento2, checkout

I'm updating a plugin and I need to add two fields.

I'd like to add them in checkout but also in user registration form.

I'm new to Magento, and I'm trying to do my best.

I found a guide here: https://oyenetwork.com/articles/magento2-devliery-date-module-creation-from-scratch/

So I begin to add the new columns to my database,

in this way:

```
public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
{
    $installer = $setup;
    $setup->startSetup();

    $installer->getConnection()->addColumn(
        $installer->getTable('quote'),
        'codice_destinatario',
        [
            'type' => 'text',
            'nullable' => false,
        ]
    );

    $installer->getConnection()->addColumn(
        $installer->getTable('quote'),
        'pec',
        [
            'type' => 'text',
            'nullable' => false,
        ]
    );

    $installer->getConnection()->addColumn(
        $installer->getTable('sales_order'),
        'codice_destinatario',
        [
            'type' => 'text',
            'nullable' => false,
        ]
    );

    $installer->getConnection()->addColumn(
        $installer->getTable('sales_order'),
        'pec',
        [
            'type' => 'text',
            'nullable' => false,
        ]
    );


    $installer->getConnection()->addColumn(
        $installer->getTable('sales_order_grid'),
        'codice_destinatario',
        [
            'type' => 'text',
            'nullable' => false,
        ]
    );
    $installer->getConnection()->addColumn(
        $installer->getTable('sales_order'),
        'pec',
        [
            'type' => 'text',
            'nullable' => false,
        ]
    );

    $setup->endSetup();
}
```

At the moment I'm not able to show my new fields in checkout.
Thanks
David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to display your fields in checkout page Use below method

etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor">
        <plugin name="add-checkout-field"
                type="Vendor\module-name\Model\Checkout\LayoutProcessorPlugin" sortOrder="10"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Vendor\module-name\Model\Checkout\LayoutProcessorPlugin.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\module-name\Model\Checkout;


class LayoutProcessor
{

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface
     */
    protected $scopeConfig;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session
     */
    protected $checkoutSession;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\AddressFactory
     */
    protected $customerAddressFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey
     */
    protected $formKey;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\CheckoutAgreements\Model\ResourceModel\Agreement\CollectionFactory $agreementCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\AddressFactory $customerAddressFactory
    ) {
        $this->scopeConfig = $context->getScopeConfig();
        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        $this->customerAddressFactory = $customerAddressFactory;
    }
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject
     * @param array $jsLayout
     * @return array
     */
    public function afterProcess(
        \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject,
        array  $jsLayout
    ) {
        $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
        ['shippingAddress']['children']['before-form']['children']['custom_field'] = [
             'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
            'config' => [
                'customScope' => 'shippingAddress',
                'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                'options' => [],
                'id' => 'custom_field_id'
            ],
            'dataScope' => 'shippingAddress.custom_field',
            'label' => 'Custom field',
            'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
            'visible' => true,
            'validation' => [],
            'sortOrder' => 200,
            'id' => 'custom_field'
        ];

        return $jsLayout;
    }


}
```

The above code will display the custom field in shipping address section you can change the position in the array $jsLayout

In order to get this value when submitting the form in checkout page. use below method

etc/extension_attributes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface">
        <attribute code="custom_field" type="string"/>
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/action/set-shipping-information': {
                'vendoe_modulename/js/action/set-shipping-information-mixin': true
            }
        } // this is how js mixin is defined
    }
};
```

view/frontend/web/js/action/set-shipping-information-mixin.js

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'mage/utils/wrapper',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote'
], function ($, wrapper, quote) {
    'use strict';

    return function (setShippingInformationAction) {

        return wrapper.wrap(setShippingInformationAction, function (originalAction) {
            var shippingAddress = quote.shippingAddress();

            if (shippingAddress['extension_attributes'] === undefined) {
                shippingAddress['extension_attributes'] = {'custom_field':'1'};                          
            }

            return originalAction();
        });
    };
});
```

The next step is saving this custom field post data to the quote. Let's make another plugin by adding an xml node in our etc/di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement">
        <plugin name="save-in-quote" type="vendor\modulename\Model\Checkout\ShippingInformationManagementPlugin" sortOrder="10"/>
</type>
```

this method will save the custom field value in quote table
vendor\modulename\Model\Checkout\ShippingInformationManagementPlugin.php

```
<?php

namespace vendor\modulename\Plugin\Checkout;

class ShippingInformationManagementPlugin
{

    protected $quoteRepository;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository $quoteRepository
    ) {
        $this->quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement $subject
     * @param $cartId
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\ShippingInformationInterface $addressInformation
     */
    public function beforeSaveAddressInformation(
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement $subject,
        $cartId,
        \Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\ShippingInformationInterface $addressInformation
    ) {
        $extAttributes = $addressInformation->getShippingAddress()->getExtensionAttributes();
        $deliveryDate = $extAttributes->getCustomField();
        $quote = $this->quoteRepository->getActive($cartId);
        $quote->setCustomField($deliveryDate);
    }
}
```

After that create another plugin to save the custom field value from quote table to sales_order table