# Magento2 Add custom billing fields order view

Tags: magento2.2, magento2.3

I added to checkout custom fields following [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/263850/add-custom-fields-in-magento-2-plugin) guide, named 'customer_pec' and 'customer_recipientcode'. For each order I save the data in quote and in quote_address tables

Now I want to add the same fields on Admin side in Order view page.

Now I want to to this (if possible): add my new custom fields under "billing address" and make them editable.

I tried to add in Customer settings -> Address Templates->HTML view
the code suggested by the comments below:

```
{{depend customer_pec}}<br /> PEC: {{var customer_pec}}{{/depend}}
```

then refresh cache, but I'm still not able to display the fields.

Edit: since I'm still stuck on this, I checked my code. I re-opened the guide and added several features including the new fields in sales_order_grid.xml:

```
<column name ="fe_data" class="Fattura24\AppFatturazione\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column\FEData">
           <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                 <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Dati FE</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/column</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="align" xsi:type="string">left</item>

                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
```

Of course I added all needed classes and templates to do this. I ran php bin/magento cache:flush but at the moment I get a blank page 'Http 500 server error' and nothing more in sales->order view.

Any debugging tool, any suggestion? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

https://drops.meetanshi.com/8DaaOk

you need to add your variable in this address template to add your custom variable to billing address

Comment: I tried to add in Address Templates strings like these:  {{var customer_pec}}, {{var customer_recipientcode}} (Text one line - store view) and these: {{depend customer_recipientcode_id}}<br />Codice Destinatario: {{var customer_recipientcode_id}}{{/depend}}
{{depend customer_pec_id}}<br />PEC: {{var customer_pec_id}}{{/depend}} (HTML - store view), then ran php bin/magento cache:flush and php bin/magento indexer:reindex but I'm not able to display new fields.

Comment: you add this in which field?

Comment: you can simple add first something like heeloo and check that it display over there of not

Comment: Now I'm able to display 'hello', but I want to retrieve data from customer_pec and customer_recipientcode input fields if customer enters something in these fields during checkout process. I save these data in quote and in quote_address tables. Actually I added these two fields in my custom checkout process, so I'd like to add the same fields in admin side, in billing address form

Comment: now you need to pass the variable name instead of hello and check , if value exist than it display

Comment: I got where's my issue: I should have data saved in sales_order table, columns => customer_pec and customer_recipientcode. I tried to add an observer to set these params but they're still void. I think I'll open a new question if I need so.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97183/discussion-between-davide-iandoli-and-jigs-parmar).

Comment: I have got customer_recipientcode and customer_pec fields in quote_address table. I tried to add {{depend customer_recipientcode}}<br /> Codice Destinatario: {{var customer_recipentcode}} {{/depend}} in HTML view. Than I ran php bin/magento cache:flush and php bin/magento indexer:reindex but cannot still display the values.